# Replace two or more character in a string using single pattern sub function in regular expression python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Replace invalid email address characters using a single regex pattern. Replace "At", "at" with "@", and replace "dot" with "."

Code:

```py
import re

email = "abc at xyz.com, abc At xyz.com, abc (at) xyz [dot] com"
pa = re.compile(r'(\s+[\(\[]*\s*at*\s*[\)\]]*\s+)',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
em = pa.sub(r'@',email)
print(em)
```

Output

```txt
abc@xyz.com, abc@xyz.com, abc@xyz [dot] com
```

Expected output

```txt
abc@xyz.com, abc@xyz.com, abc@xyz.com
```

How can I replace '[dot]' with  '.'?

Answer (score 0):

Requiring the substitution to happen with a single pattern just pushes the problem to a different corner. In brief, the second argument to `re.sub` can be a function of arbitrary complexity, but then requiring that function to be inlined to a single line seems somewhat disingenuous.

Here, we create a `re.sub` which uses a simple dictionary to decide what to replace the match with.

```
import re

email = "abc at xyz.com, abc At xyz.com, abc (at) xyz [dot] com"
pa = re.compile(r'\W*(at|dot)\W*', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
em = pa.sub(lambda m: {'dot': '.', 'at': '@'}[m.group(1).lower()], email)
print(em)
```

The main trick is to capture just the dictionary key into the parenthesized subexpression, which is then available in `.group(1)`.

Demo: https://ideone.com/3Llu0i